# Webpack doesn't bundle images referenced only in HTML

Tags: html, webpack, config, task-runner-explorer

I've encountered a strangle problem which I'm unable to solve on my own. My webpack config doesn't compile imagenes from my source directory to build directory when they are only referenced from in HTML, while it does compile imagenes referenced in css without any problems. Here's my webpack.config.file:

```
            var webpack = require('webpack');
            var path = require('path');


            module.exports = {
                entry: {
                    bundle: './js/app.js',
                    vendor: 'jquery'
                },
                output: {
                    path: path.resolve('./build'),
                    filename: "[name].js",
                    publicPath: './build/'
                },
                plugins: [
                    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'vendor', filename: 'vendor.js', minChunks: Infinity })],
                watch: true,
                module: {
                    loaders: [{
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        query: {
                            presets: ['es2015']
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.scss$/,
                        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                        loaders: [{
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: 'img/[name].[ext]',
                                context: '',
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                            query: {

                                mozjpeg: {
                                    progressive: true,
                                },
                                gifsicle: {
                                    interlaced: false,
                                },
                                optipng: {
                                    optimizationLevel: 5,
                                },
                                pngquant: {
                                    quality: '75-90',
                                    speed: 5,
                                },
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    },

                    {
                        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                        loader: 'url-loader'
                    },


                    {
                        test: /\.(html)$/,
                        use: {
                            loader: 'html-loader',
                            options: {
                                attrs: [':img-src']
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ]
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `html-loader` will only process the attributes that are specified in the `attrs` option in the form of `<tag>:<attribute>`. You are using `:img-src`, that means match any tag (because the value before the `:` is empty) and process the attribute `img-src`.

What you want is to process the `src` attribute of the `img` tag:

```
{
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
        attrs: ['img:src']
    }
}
```

That is already the default of `html-loader` (see [README - Usage](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#usage)), which means that you don't need to configure that option.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work, even if i remove the additional options. The only workaround i can see is to move all images to css files

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. You still have to copy the images to dist by using CopyWebpackPlugin.